# How to fire a function only once in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I am building a **Star Wars Search Application** where I have an object full of **Star Wars Character Information**, You can dynamically search through the object using a map function that matches it to a Regular Expression that fires as the user is searching for a character.

That all works perfectly but I have added the functionality for the user to click on a character (e.g **Luke Skywalker**) this will then append HTML to the view and add information regarding **Luke**. I am struggling to get this function to only fire once, user can click multiple times on the character and it will keep on adding the same content.

How can I only allow the user to click on the `<li>` once so that the function `displayInfo()` will fire once.

Thanks for the help.

```
var newView = document.querySelector(".starwars");

function displayInfo() {

    newView.innerHTML += `
      <div class="jedi">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
          <img id="swImage"src="img"
              class="thumb reserved-ratio" alt="Luke Skywalker">
      </div>
      <div class="desc-sizer">
          <p class="desc">Luke Skywalker was a Tatooine farmboy who rose from humble beginnings to become one of the greatest Jedi the galaxy
              has ever known.
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
      `;
    searchInput.value = 'Luke Skywalker';
    searchInput.addEventListener("focus", displayMatches);
    searchInput.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

[`EventTarget.addEventListener()` Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters):

**Options:** *Optional*

> `once`: A Boolean indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. If `true`, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked.

You can pass `{ once: true }` to `addEventListener()` as the third parameter:

```
searchInput.addEventListener("focus", displayMatches, { once: true });
```

**Demo:**

```js
function displayInfo() {
  var searchInput = document.querySelector('.searchInput');
  searchInput.value = 'Luke Skywalker';
  searchInput.addEventListener("focus", displayMatches, {once: true});
  searchInput.focus();
}
displayInfo();
function displayMatches(){
  alert('This function will be invoked only once!!!');
}
```

```html
<input class="searchInput" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether it's already inserted.

```
if (newView.innerHTML.indexOf("Luke Skywalker") < 0) {
    // code to insert 

}
```